# Symbols in parent module are not available in an exported submodule

Tags: module, typescript

I have a something like the following structure

```
export module Foo {
   export var DEBUG = false;
}

module Foo.Utils {
   export function fooFunc() : void { if(Foo.DEBUG) doIt() }
}
```

This works fine. I can do `Foo.Utils.fooFunc()` without problems.

The thing is that WebStorm highlights references to Foo.Utils and says "the private member is not accessible". I then tried exporting the module to avoid this error, but now the typescript compiler borks and gives me

```
The property 'DEBUG' does not exist on value of type 'typeof Foo'. 
Warning: Task "typescript:all" failed. Use --force to continue.
```

Why does this happen, and how can I achieve my intended goal of referencing Foo.DEBUG in the submodule while keeping the module non-private?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to export a module from a file but *want* it split into multiple segements you can do the following :

```
module Foo {
   export var DEBUG = false;
}

module Foo.Utils {
   export function fooFunc() : void { if(Foo.DEBUG) doIt() }
}

export = Foo;
```

That said. You don't *need* to use internal modules if you are using *external* modules. Here's the difference : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1

Comment: sorry for awarding you the answer two years later. i _did_ use the info at the time, though :)